# error generating random number in python

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to generate 10 random numbers which are multiples of 5 in the range 1 to 100

```
import random
f = []
for x in range(1,10):
    f = random.randint(1,101)
    for i in range(10):
        while f(i)%5.0 == 0.0: #multiples of 5
            print f(i)
```

But it's showing

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Any help

Comment: Well `f` in an integer, what is `f(i)` supposed to do?

Comment: you probably mean `f = lambda : random.randint(1,101)`. Bar that: why would you pass a parameter as input?

Comment: f has 10 values I wish to find only those values which are multiples of 5 thus I looped over the f array

Comment: `f = [i * 5 for i in random.sample(range(1, 21), 10)]`.

Answer (score 1):

couple things that went wrong with your code:

1:You don't need `f = []` since you overwrite it with an integer.

2:The `while` loop will not exit once you hit a number that is a multiple of 5, which will crash your console. It will keep printing. Use `if` instead.

3: Use `[]` instead of `()` to access an element by index

```
import random
for x in range(1,10):
    f = random.randint(1,101)
    if f%5.0 == 0.0:
        print f
```

If you are trying to add the integer to a list f, then you need to append it, do `f.append`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the

```
f = []
```

I think you can do this

```
import random
for _ in range(10):
    f = random.randint(1,21) * 5
    print(f)
```